# Changing card position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a card game in unity. I have 4 cards and instantiated them randomly 16 times on 4 zones when a button is clicked. Each zone contains 4 random cards. I want to know how can I know which card is in which zone and then change the position of that particular card to another zone.

**This is the script attached to each of my card:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Canvas;
    public GameObject MyArea;
    private bool isDragging=false;
    private bool isOverBottomArea=false;
    private GameObject BottomArea;
    private GameObject startParent;
    private Vector2 startPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        MyArea=GameObject.Find("MyArea");
        Canvas=GameObject.Find("Canvas");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            transform.position= new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y);
            transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform, true);
            
        }
       
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        isOverBottomArea=true;
        BottomArea=collision.gameObject;
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        isOverBottomArea=false;
        BottomArea=null;
    }

    public void StartDrag()
    {
        
        startParent= transform.parent.gameObject;
        startPosition=transform.position;
        if(startParent != MyArea)
        {
            isDragging=false;
        }
        else
        {
            isDragging=true;
        }
    }

    public void EndDrag()
    {
        isDragging=false;
        if (isOverBottomArea && startParent==MyArea )
        {
            transform.SetParent(BottomArea.transform, false);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position=startPosition;
            transform.SetParent(startParent.transform, false);
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is the script attached to the button which on clicking instantiate the 16 cards:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawCards : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Card1;
    public GameObject Card2;
    public GameObject Card3;
    public GameObject Card4;
    public GameObject MyArea;
    public GameObject LeftArea;
    public GameObject RightArea;
    public GameObject BottomArea;

    List<GameObject> cards = new List<GameObject>();


    void Start()
    {
        cards.Add(Card1);
        cards.Add(Card2);
        cards.Add(Card3);
        cards.Add(Card4);
        
    }
    
    int count1 = 0;
 public void OnClick()
 {
    count1++;
    if (count1 == 1)
    {
         for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
      {
         GameObject playerCard = Instantiate(cards[Random.Range(0, cards.Count)], new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
         playerCard.transform.SetParent(MyArea.transform, false);

         GameObject leftCard = Instantiate(cards[Random.Range(0, cards.Count)], new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
         leftCard.transform.SetParent(LeftArea.transform, false);

         GameObject rightCard = Instantiate(cards[Random.Range(0, cards.Count)], new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
         rightCard.transform.SetParent(RightArea.transform, false);

         GameObject bottomCard = Instantiate(cards[Random.Range(0, cards.Count)], new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
         bottomCard.transform.SetParent(BottomArea.transform, false);
      }
    }
   
 }
    
}
```

Comment: Just store each card type in each zone with identifiers as to which card it is. You need to provide code as to what a card is, how you are spawning them, what zones are, etc. to get a more in-depth answer.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zItxHmzwmOekagy1vwhQGFrgD_lXUfNl1sm06BqluuE/edit?usp=sharing kindly view this file to access my codes, I cannot put it through stack overflow

Comment: @TEEBQNE has submitted an edit adding your code to your question but technically that violates copyright without your permission. Can you approve the edit or leave a comment stating the edit is OK so it can be approved by others?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider storing the values to each of your 4 zones with card data to be utilized later. I do not exactly know what a zone is or what it means if there can be more than 4 cards to a zone, etc.

Here is a very general approach to having zones, cards and a zone manager. I can help clarify any details as to what the code does but I commented it quite extensively. I did not integrate it into your code but rather it should be used as a template by you to do so. The code I am providing is untested and should not just be copy-pasted as your question is still rather general. I can explain anything further if you need.

**Card class on each moveable card**

```
// this class is on each of your cards
public class Card : MonoBehaviour, 
{
    // current index of this card
    private int cardIndex = -1;
    
    // stores the current zone this card is in
    private Zone currentZone = null;
    
    // init this object with the zone it is in and the card index it has
    public void InitCard(Zone zone, int idx)
    {
        cardIndex = idx;
        currentZone = zone;
    }
    
    // I am using the same EndDrag - I am assuming you are using an editor component of EventTrigger with an 
    // OnBeginDrag and OnEndDrag instead of implementing the IHandlers in code
    public void EndDrag()
    {
        // determine if we are over a zone - I am going to use the MouseInput as with a drag, 
        // you would be dragging the object using the cursor or a finger 
        
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        
        // only look for the layer of the Zone objects
        // make sure to add a layer to just the zones and make sure
        // it is spelled / case-sensative so exactly the same
        int layer_mask = LayerMask.GetMask("ZoneLayer");
        
        // if we hit a zone, determine if it is a new zone and to move the card
        if(Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layer_mask))
        {
            Zone newZone = hit.gameObject.GetComponent<Zone>();
            
            // we hit a zone, is it the same zone?
            if(currentZone == newZone)
            {
                // handle however you want to do a case where it is the same zone
                // reset the card position possibly
                return;
            }
            
            // we are in a new zone, so need to remove this card from the old zone and add it to the new one
            // I am not sure how you are handling max card counts in each zone, etc. so this is very basic implementation
            currentZone.RemoveCard(this);
            newZone.AddCard(this);
            
            // update our local zone reference
            currentZone = newZone;
        }  
    }
    
    // setters / getters
    public int CardIndex
    {
        set{cardIndex = value;}
        get{return cardIndex;}
    }
    
    public Zone CurrentZone
    {
        set{currentZone = value;}
        get{return currentZone;}
    }
}
```

**ZoneManager should be on an object that manages your individual zones, so possibly the Canvas object that all of this data is on**

```
// this class will manage each one of your zones
public class ZoneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // list of our prefabs
    [SerializeField] private List<GameObjects> allCardsPrefabList = new List<GameObjects>();

    // create a list of zone data of size 4
    [SerializeField] private Zone[] myZoneData = new Zone[MAX_ZONE_COUNT]; 
    
    // max number of zones we can have
    private const int MAX_ZONE_COUNT = 4;
    
    // max number of cards we can have on Init
    private const int MAX_INIT_CARD_COUNT = 4; 
    
    // init our zones in Start() - as I do not know if you are working with UI
    // and UI components are only set before Start but not Awake
    private void Start()
    {
        // iterate over each zone
        for(int x = 0; x < MAX_ZONE_COUNT; ++x)
        {
            // iterate over 4 new cards
            for(int y = 0; y < MAX_INIT_CARD_COUNT; ++y)
            {
                // I am using this overload of the Instantiate
                // public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent, bool instantiateInWorldSpace);
                
                // grab our new idx
                int newCardIdx = Random.Range(0, cards.Count);
                
                // spawn a new card childed to our zone at the new card idx
                Card newCard = Instantiate(allCardsPrefabList[newCardIdx], myZoneData[x].transform, false).GetComponent<Card>(); 
                
                // init our card zone / idx
                newCard.Init(myZoneData[x], newCardIdx);
                
                // add this card to a zone
                myZoneData[x].AddNewCard(newCard);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The Zone class should be on each of your individual zones**

```
// this is a script that will house each of your zones and will be used to add cards to your zone
public class Zone : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const int MAX_INIT_CARDS = 4;
    
    // list of our current cards of this zone
    public List<CardData> zoneCards = new List<CardData>();  
    
    // called from when a cast is detected on a drop
    public void AddNewCard(Card newCard)
    {
        zoneCards.Add(newCard);
    }
    
    // remove a card instance from our list as it is no longer apart of this zone
    public void RemoveCard(Card oldCard)
    {
        zoneCards.Remove(oldCard);
    }
}
```

Again, this is a general idea, not a straightforward answer. Use it as a template to add to your existing code.